# Implementing Stack's Pop method with Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I am self-studying java. I have been studying data structures for the past couple of days. I am reading the book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java". there is an exercise that I have problem with. it asks for implementing the pop method with recursion so that when the method is called it should delete all the items at once. can anyone help on this? a pointer on how to do it would be much appreciated. thanks. (following is the pop method currently implemented).

```
    public double pop() // take item from top of stack
{


        return stackArray[top--]; // access item, decrement top
}
```

Comment: You need to call pop from within pop.

Comment: what i did up until now is i tried to change the method to something like this pop(int Top), where "top" refers to the last item on the stack. then called it recursively. had a base case like top == -1, but it didn't work.

Comment: Search on google by typing the keyword - `"Recursion"`.. You will find many examples.. It is not programming language specific.. So, you don't have to worry about language...  Before implementing, you should get a feel of `Recursion` on your notebook..

Comment: @Deewanagan.. thats meaningless.. As pop() is used to pop the top element only.. You don't need to pass it.. `pop()` should not take any parameter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every one, i solved the problem. don't know if efficient, but i did like below:

```
    public void pop()
{

    if(isEmpty()){

        return;
    }

    if (top>=0){

        stackArray[top] = stackArray[top--];
        pop();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

First IMO you should understand how to implement a non-recursive counterpart of this method.

It can be something like this:

```
public void popAll() {

  while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
      stack.pop();
  }
}
```

Once you understand this, the recursive version should be easy:

```
public void popAllRecursive() {

     if(stack.isEmpty()) {
        //nothing to remove, return
        return;
     }
     stack.pop();  // remove one stack element

     popAllRecursive(); // recursive invocation of your method

}
```

Since its an exercise I just provide you an idea and leave the implementation to you (you can consider to provide the method in class Stack and use the top counter and stackArray - an implementation of your stack.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about the base case where there is nothing in the stack, i.e. `stack.pop() == null`.

For the recursive case, it is quite intuitive as you just need to recursively call `pop()` until the base case is met.

Comment: yeah but my problem is how to call it again, i mean i need to somehow change the pointer top (decrement it) right? i am not able to do that

Comment: I think you should do something like:
`if(baseCase) return; else System.Out.println(stack.pop());`
Put the whole block in your `pop` method so that it gets called repeatedly until the base case is hit.

Answer (score 0):

Call `pop()` repeatedly till end of stack. 
As you have not mentioned how the data is stored cant help you providing code.

Comment: the data is stored in an ARRAY

Comment: So you jus need to call `pop()` till array is empty :)